# Mysql Query to show exact 7 days expiring clients

Tags: mysql

I am having a bit of difficulty in getting the right value.

What I want to query is, the users who expire in 7 days, for example on 4th Oct 2011, the query should display the result of that particular day only. Right now I am querying as below:

```
select * from users where exp_date between now() and adddate(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY).
```

this query keep display till next 7 days.

But i want to show only for on 7th day expiring clients as I move on to tomorrow's date then the today's displayed query should not display on tomorrow's display rather it show the expiring client on 5th Oct 2011 and so on.

How do I achieve this? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY This:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE exp_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Make sure your `exp_date` field is `DATE` type

Comment: thanks to you all for helping me, I got this answer from another forum. Appreciate... answer is... WHERE TO_DAYS(exp_date) - TO_DAYS(NOW()) = 7 :)

Comment: Cool. You should select one answer that helped you most so others could benefit from that too :)

Comment: i think yours is much simpler and easy than the other and I recommend yours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`WHERE exp_date = CURDATE()+7`

You may add days or subtract days as you move on calender like this:
`WHERE exp_date = CURDATE()+7+$daysoffset`
where `$daysoffset` is 0 for Today, 1 for Tomorrow.

Comment: I also tried with this, but results are same as above mentioned. `exp_date` <= ADDDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND `exp_date` >= NOW()